# Looking for an app for "boosting" dark photos

Tags: applications, images

I've used an app called "color touch" for boosting dark images whilst maintaining the global contrast (similar to PhotoShop).  Unfortunately this app doesn't work anymore since I flashed my Galaxy S2 with CyanogenMod v10.

So I'm wondering, is there a similar app which allows boosting dark images (e.g. from inside a club)?

Answer (score 2):

[Photoshop Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.psmobile) comes to mind.